# replace words of a string mantain lowercase and uppercase chars of original string

Tags: php

I have, for example, this string `$string='Hello World, hello world';`
I have a parameter in lowercase or uppercase and I need to replace all the equal words for `<stong>word</strong>`

If i try this:
`$newstring=str_ireplace('world','<strong>world<s/trong>',$string);`

The result are **Hello world, hello world** (lowercase w in the first word) is to be posssible replace string mantain lowercases and upercases of the original string?

Thanks, sorry for my english

Answer (score 4):

This is easily done with [preg_replace](http://php.net/preg_replace).

```
$string = preg_replace('/world/i', '<strong>$0</strong>', $string);
```